# Writing tests that run on both Android and desktop

Tags: android, testing, junit, libgdx

Lately I noticed a bug in my Android app which doesn't happen when I run the same code on the desktop (since the app is written on top of libgdx, 99% of the code is the same on desktop and Android.) I decided to explore why by writing some unit tests. However, while the tests run fine on the desktop, I get the "Failed to launch test" error when I try to run the tests on Android:

```
[2013-03-09 19:06:45 - zzz-test-android] Installing zzz-test-android.apk...
[2013-03-09 19:06:48 - zzz-test-android] Success!
[2013-03-09 19:06:48 - zzz-test-android] Launching instrumentation android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner on 015d15b51d30180b
[2013-03-09 19:06:48 - zzz-test-android] Failed to launch test
```

The way my project is set up in Eclipse is that I have two projects: A "zzz-test" which contains the test classes and the JUnit3 libs. Then a second "zzz-test-android" project (which was created via "New Android Test Project") which has a dependency on zzz-test.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong, or at least a way to get an error message that might be more helpful?

Comment: logcat should tell you why it failed to launch the test.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be related with some missing permission in manifest file?